# Difference between flatten on keras and Image in python

Tags: python, keras

I wanted to ask that is there any difference between the keras.flatten() layer and flatten() of Image from PIL library in python.

Comment: I am not seeing any `flatten` function in PIL. Do you have a pointer?

Comment: Did you mean the Keras backend flatten function, or the Flatten layer? All of them provide analogous results, but the ones in Keras are symbolic, ie: the operation is only performed when you run the graph, while the PIL one is performed straight away. Take a look at http://mxnet.io/architecture/program_model.html#symbolic-vs-imperative-programs .